# checkBox setButtonDrawable color Android

Tags: android, checkbox, color

Estoy intentando color algunos iconos al checkbox, como se ve en la imagen uno son a color, pero cuando se cargan en la aplicación me pone un tono gris, para ambos iconos, alguien sabe como arreglarlo?

[image: Iconos a color]

[image: Como se ve]

Answer (score 0):

Intenta actualizando el tint del button.

```
<CheckBox
    android:id="@+id/check"
    app:buttonTint="@color/checkbox_tint"/>


<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:color="@color/YOUR_COLOR_FOR_UNCHECKED" 
          android:state_checked="false"/>
    <item android:color="@color/YOUR_COLOR_FOR_CHECKED"
          android:state_checked="true"/>
</selector>
```

Comment: Estoy utilizando un recurso de drawable (vector asset) y los iconos que estoy usando se ven en la primer imagen a color, pero en la aplicación me muestra un tono a escala de grises.